# Include Line Breaks with htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

I am creating a pattern library similar to A List Apart's here: http://patterns.alistapart.com/. I am using the following code snippet to grab the contents of the HTML file and output it on the page (see the code area on A List Apart's example):

```
echo "<code class=\"col-md-8 col-sm-6 prettyprint pattern-markup language-markup\">".htmlspecialchars(@file_get_contents($dir.'/'.$ff))."</code>\n";
```

It is pulling in the code, but is stripping out all line breaks in the HTML so the code all runs together. Is it possible to add the line breaks back into the code view? I know `nl2br` is an option, but that works if I was outputting the HTML in visual mode, not code.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything that is stripping `newlines`. If your intended output is HTML then `nl2br` is correct. Also, be careful in using `@`. In this case use of `@` is unwarranted. Do a `file_exists` and `is_readable` check on the file if you're unsure.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Thanks for the reply. If you look at the A List Apart example it seems to not be stripping the new lines, which is what I want. When I use their same code (above) it is stripping the new lines though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has absolutely nothing to do with stripping newlines and everything to do with how basic HTML works.

Try this:

```
<p>Hello





World</p>
```

Do you see newlines? Nope.

Try applying the CSS `white-space: pre-wrap` to your element.

Comment: Ah ha, it was a CSS solution. Didn't even think of that. Thanks so much for the help, this is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

**Just Use pre tags** And everything will work fine. But put codes like this

```html
<pre>Start from here
Not from here
</pre>
```